# Placeholder for wiget area while content is loading

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a Widget that grabs content from a remote database. Quite often it loads slower than the page. Initially, while it's loading, it has a smaller profile than what it eventually ends up with. It causes issues for a number of reasons to do with page rendering.

The Widget loads some album art. Is there a method to perhaps load a placeholder jpeg, so that visually the widget has continuity, but also the page loads without changes to size and layout when the real content arrives?

I'm not 100% sure about what I can post here as an example or attempt. But I can dig in to the current Wordpress plugin if required.

Example [here](http://www.budgiecollective.com/news/) - Scroll up and down while the page is loading and see the album art load in the left sidebar.

My attempt...

```
/* IMAGE PLACEHOLDER */

#samsonginfo_widget_li_djart::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x150");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#samsonginfo_widget_li_djart::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x150");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#samsonginfo_widget_li_djart:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x150");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#samsonginfo_widget_li_djart:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10- */
  color: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x150");
  background-position: 0 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Sorry forgot the link. See my edit:)

Comment: Hmm tricky without knowing the name of the widget you are using, I would just use a min-height CSS rule to style the widget area and give it a placeholder background image

Comment: It's a custom Widget, and the dev has left the building! But that sounds good. I can do that. What's the syntax for the latter? I'll give it a try.

Comment: OK I added my attempt, it's not basic to me. Hopefully you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's the answer:

```
.samsonginfo_widget {
     min-height:265px;
     background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x150");
     background-position: left bottom;
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
.samsonginfo_widget ul {
     background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this worked! You can see now on the link. Thanks for helping with such a vague question. Any ideas around how to handle the heading and text?

Comment: The placeholder image loads while the rest is loading, but there is a space below the heading "On Air", and the text below the album art has no placeholder, which means the content resizes once it loads.

Comment: Just change the min height and background position of the placeholder until its right for you. Good luck

Comment: Actually, I find the placement is fine without specifying the image. (line... `background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x150");`) Although I'd like to have an image if possible. Maybe a self hosted one would be better.